# set url to refresh token JWT in grails using spring security rest

Tags: grails, spring-security-rest

I´m using spring security rest. Actually to refresh token im using this url: `/oauth/access_token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=token`

However i'm using api rest and I want to use `/api/oauth` to refresh token instead of `/oauth.`

I tried redirect in `urlMappings`, but response 404 not found.

```
"/api/oauth"(redirect: '/oauth')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "/api/oauth"(redirect: '/oauth')

As you found, that mapping won't work but there may not be a good reason to use a redirect anyway.  The plugin provides a mapping like this:

```
"/oauth/access_token"(controller: 'restOauth', action: 'accessToken')
```

(see https://github.com/alvarosanchez/grails-spring-security-rest/blob/d5940921b4aea466a961957e0599321d01e4c6de/spring-security-rest/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity/rest/RestOauthUrlMappings.groovy#L24)

You can map whatever url you like to that controller.  You could do this...

```
"/api/oauth"(controller: 'restOauth', action: 'accessToken')
```

Answer (score 0):

*** Work for me grails spring refresh token
-method : Post
-http://localhost:8085/oauth/access_token?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={your_access_token}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).